# About AOSP Downloading & Building Few Queries

Tags: android, open-source, android-source, rom

I have Lubuntu 12.10 on my machine. All necessary software's are installed for compiling AOSP.
I have android mobile with ver. 2.3 I did not found any ROM ver. 4.0 for it so decided to compile it my self. I am following [this guide](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html).

The last commands i ran are:

```
$ repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.0.4_r2.1
$ repo sync
```

Now's it's more than 1 day still it's only synchronizing. Download speed is around 50 kbps.
So my Question No.1 :is for compiling to AOSP android-4.0.4_r2.1 is there any other's way that i can skip unnecessary files and download only 4.0 necessary files?

Question No.2 : I found one more link that is for only building kernels [here](http://source.android.com/source/building-kernels.html). So if i follow this guide will it be same as repo sync that i ran cause i have specified -b android-4.0.4_r2.1
What will be faster way to download only for AOSP 4.0 and any specific guide to build it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have read the warning on AOSP download page, if your download speed is about 50kb/s, it might take a **very long time** (~ a few days?) to download about 10GB of different files required to build AOSP.

Also, if you don't have a Google Nexus device, most probably the image you build won't work with your device. It takes **a lot** of tinkering to add the support for the very specific hardware you have in your phone.

Of course, nobody can forbid you downloading sources and building the image, but I would strongly advise against it, because in your case basically it's pointless waste of time.

Comment: I am also thinking now to stop the download. And Yes i read but thought it's for full source code. So you mean there is no way to download for only AOSP 4.0 or it's source code size is large? Is there any other way that i can port android 4.0 to my device?

Comment: what is your device (maker, model)? search the internet, if nobody did this yet, most probably you won't be able to do that too.

Comment: it is Karbonn A7 also known as K-touch W650 and Mobiistar Touch S01. And no one did this yet.

Comment: 512MB of internal memory, hardly enough for 4.0.* versions, sorry.

Comment: My ISP (SLT) gives 16mbits internet. I am going to download ASOP on my off-peak so how long will it take (off-peak is 12:00am to 8:00am).

Answer (score 0):

Finally found ICS for Karbonn A7. This guy made a tutorial for it. This is update 2.
[Tutorial Here](http://iamrainwalker.wordpress.com/2012/12/28/symphony-w25-ktouch-w650-mobistar-s01-karbonn-a7-ics-rom-update-2).